# improve performance of wrap_content height recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedrecyclerview

I have 3 vertical recycler view in a screen inside a `NestedScrollView` like:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I need to set `recycler-view`'s height `wrap_content` because the contents are dynamic. When I'm calling `submitList(...)`, the 60-80 frames skipped. Child views are cheap and simple and the total items for showing in all of them are about 30.

When I hardcoded the `recycler-view`'s height for example 100dp there's no skipped frame in the result!

How can I fix this issue or improve this function?

P.S: I can't merge them together by an adapter with multiple view-type.

Comment: If your recyclerViewItems have static size then you can use `setHasFixedSize()` on recyclerViews. i can't say this method solve your problem but it can imporove your performance.

Comment: Ok, why do you have 3 RecyclerViews in a NestedScrollVIew? What are you trying to achieve here? To begin with, a RecyclerView won't recycle anything when in a ScrollView...